# Remove row if does not contain the same value in column pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Hello I have a dataframe such as

```
COL1 COL2 
A    seq1
B    seq1
A    seq2
A    seq3
A    seq4
A    seq5
B    seq9
B    seq4
```

And I would like to only keep row where **A** and **B** within `COL1` have the same `COL2` value.

I should then get;

```
COL1 COL2 
A    seq1
B    seq1
A    seq4
B    seq4
```

Does someone have an idea please ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can group by `COL2` (unintuitive, isn't it?), and get the number of unique items of `COL1` for each group:

```
filtered_df = df[df.groupby('COL2')['COL1'].transform('nunique') == 2]
```

Output:

```
>>> filtered_df
  COL1  COL2
0    A  seq1
1    B  seq1
4    A  seq4
7    B  seq4
```

Answer (score 3):

If you `COL1` has only 2 values, you could also filter `df` for values in "COL1", `merge` on `COL2`; then `melt`:

```
out = (pd.melt(df[df['COL1']=='A'].merge(df[df['COL1']=='B'], on='COL2'), 
               id_vars=['COL2'], value_name='COL1')
       .drop(columns='variable')[['COL1', 'COL2']])
```

Output:

```
  COL1  COL2
0    A  seq1
1    A  seq4
2    B  seq1
3    B  seq4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `pd.crosstab`:

```
seq = pd.crosstab(df['COL1'], df['COL2']).all().loc[lambda x: x].index
out = df.loc[df['COL2'].isin(seq)]
print(out)

# Output
  COL1  COL2
0    A  seq1
1    B  seq1
4    A  seq4
7    B  seq4
```

Intermediate result:

```
>>> pd.crosstab(df['COL1'], df['COL2'])
COL2  seq1  seq2  seq3  seq4  seq5  seq9
COL1                                    
A        1     1     1     1     1     0
B        1     0     0     1     0     1
```